# Non removable watermark on PDF file using iText in Java

Tags: java, pdf, itext, watermark

We have a requirement where we need to add text watermark on magazines which has multiple rich images on each page. I tried `com.itextpdf.jar version 5.0.6` to add the watermark but eventually I am **able to remove** it using Adobe Acrobat Pro.

I tried below option also but that too didn't work.

```
stamper.setFreeTextFlattening(true);
```

Is it possible with iText to add a watermark which can not be removed without much effort.

Below is my implementation.

```
public static void addWaterMark() throws IOException, DocumentException {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("C:/Trade-catalog/Catalog2017.pdf");
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputPdf = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, outputPdf);

    String bodyWatermarkText = "12345 - John Smith";
    String bodyWatermarkRotation = "35";
    String footerWatermarkText = "Richard Parker";
    BaseFont font = BaseFont.createFont("/fonts/micross.ttf", "Cp1250", BaseFont.EMBEDDED);

    PdfGState state = new PdfGState();
    state.setFillOpacity(0.3f);

    for (int i = 1; i <= reader.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
        Rectangle thisPageSize = reader.getPageSize(i);
        PdfPatternPainter bodyPainter = stamper.getOverContent(i).createPattern(thisPageSize.getWidth(),
                thisPageSize.getHeight());
        bodyPainter.setColorFill(new BaseColor(0, 0, 0));
        bodyPainter.beginText();
        bodyPainter.setTextRenderingMode(PdfPatternPainter.TEXT_RENDER_MODE_FILL);
        bodyPainter.setFontAndSize(font, 60);
        bodyPainter.showTextAlignedKerned(Element.ALIGN_CENTER, bodyWatermarkText, thisPageSize.getWidth() / 2,
                thisPageSize.getHeight() / 2, Integer.valueOf(bodyWatermarkRotation));
        bodyPainter.showTextAlignedKerned(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT, footerWatermarkText, thisPageSize.getWidth() * 0.97f,
                thisPageSize.getHeight() * 0.015f, 0);
        bodyPainter.endText();

        PdfContentByte overContent = stamper.getOverContent(i);
        overContent.setGState(state);
        overContent.setColorFill(new PatternColor(bodyPainter));
        overContent.rectangle(thisPageSize.getLeft(), thisPageSize.getBottom(), thisPageSize.getWidth(),
                thisPageSize.getHeight());
        overContent.fill();
        overContent.setFlatness(100);
    }
    stamper.close();
    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(
            "C:/Trade-catalog/output/TradeCatalog2017Watermarked_bodyPainter.pdf");
    outputPdf.writeTo(outputStream);
    outputPdf.close();
    reader.close();
}
```

Comment: Unless you flatten everything into a single bitmap (which you don't want to do), posting an answer here with code to add currently non-removable watermarks would not only help you create them but also everyone interested in watermark removal remove them. That being said, iText 5.0.6 is ancient.

Comment: FYI: 5.5.13 is the most recent in the 5-series, and 7.1.4 in the 7-series.